# Build RegEx to put children ul in li tags in php string?

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to RegEx and I'm looking for the simplest way to add li around some children ul of another ul. Example I got :

[image]

And I would like :

[image]

I tried several ways, but my main problem is to put into regex that the replacement occurs only ul children of another ul (I tried to use preg_replace)

Do you have any idea or any suggestion?

Many thanks for your help,

Nicolas

Comment: If you want to spend the least time making a prototype that works you can *maybe* use a regex. But if you want to spend the least time banging your head on the wall in the long run, leave it alone and use DOM manipulation instead.

Comment: +1 for DOM, not a place for regex.

Comment: OK, guys, many thanks for that. I tried your solution Cylian but for some reason it didn't work... I would prefer a lot using DOM, but how can I replace tags that are used to parse (i.e. ul). 

May I ask you an example ?

Cheers !

Comment: @Nicolas: I've updated my solution. Is it ok now?

Comment: Please.. [do not use regexes to parse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/298479) or even modify HTML. A DOM engine does the job much, **much** better!

Comment: Cylian, still don't work. Return result is null. Thanks again !
@ThiefMaster : I agree with you but with something like this http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php how can I modify the source considering the fact that I want target and modify some tags and not filtering or extract content? Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$result = preg_replace('%(?s)(?<=</li>)(\s*<ul>.+?</ul>)%im', '<li>$1</li>', $subject);
```

**RegEx explanation:**

```
<!--
(?is)(?<=</li>)(\s*<ul>.+?</ul>)

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i); dot matches newline (s) «(?is)»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=</li>)»
   Match the characters “</li>” literally «</li>»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\s*<ul>.+?</ul>)»
   Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match the characters “<ul>” literally «<ul>»
   Match any single character «.+?»
      Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
   Match the characters “</ul>” literally «</ul>»
-->
```